# Passing Information Through a Segue

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview, nsstring, uistoryboardsegue

I'm attempting to obtain the HTML code from a UITextView and let users view it, live, in a UIWebView in the next segue. Here is what I have so far.

- DetailViewController - *view with UITextView:*

  - UITextView: `codeView`
- PreviewViewController - *view with UIWebView*

  - UIWebView: `webView`
  - UIWebView Code: `webViewCode`

**DetailViewController**

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    // Get the new view controller using [segue destinationViewController].
    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"webViewCode"]) {
        PreviewViewController *preview = [segue destinationViewController];
        preview.webViewCode = self.codeView.text;

        self.preview.webViewCode = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:codeView.text];
        [[segue destinationViewController] setWebViewCode:codeView.text];
    }

}
```

**PreviewViewController**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    [webView loadHTMLString:webViewCode baseURL:nil];
}
```

Everything is connected in the interface builder, including the Storyboard Segue Identifier. As you can see I've tried multiple ways on passing the information through but have only come up with errors. Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: What errors do you get? Be specific.

Comment: You must have some null value there, have you tried stepping into the code?

Comment: @matt No errors, but the WebView isn't turning up anything - just blank. My apologies for not including that in my original post.

Comment: @ryudice How do you mean?

Answer (score 0):

This code does not make sense:

```
if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"webViewCode"]) {
    PreviewViewController *preview = [segue destinationViewController];
    preview.webViewCode = self.codeView.text;

    self.preview.webViewCode = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:codeView.text];
    [[segue destinationViewController] setWebViewCode:codeView.text];
}
```

You create a local variable preview, of type PreviewViewController. As the other poster pointed out, you need to add a typecast to this to avoid a compiler warning:

```
    PreviewViewController *preview = 
      (PreviewViewController*) [segue destinationViewController];
```

The real problem, though, is that you then ignore the local variable you just defined, and try to use a property, self.preview, which is backed by a completely different instance variable, and probably nil. Don't do that. get rid of the "self." bit in this line:

```
    preview.webViewCode = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:codeView.text];
```

And then delete the line below completely, since it does the same thing as the line before.